# Higher order extensions of gaussian distribution?

Tags: covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

I anticipate that this question may be predicated on some misconceptions or confusion. Please have patience.

Through Bishop's PR&ML book, as well as a little bit of exposure to statistical mechanics, I understand that the Gaussian distribution has maximal entropy for a given choice of first and second order moments. For multivariate statistics this is still true, and the complete description of second order moments is an order 2 tensor, i.e. the covariance matrix.

My question is: Is there a natural extension that takes these properties to higher order moments, for example, using an order 3 tensor for the 3rd order statistics? Is this sort of construction ever used?

Edit: I rephrased the question in the comments below:

> If all I know are the mean and covariance of a random variable, then there are infinitely many distributions it might have. However, among all such distributions the Gaussian best represents my state of knowledge. The question then is, what distribution should I assume if I also knew all of the third order moments. It seems as though I can find such a distribution via Boltzmann's theorem, but I'm interested in whether this approach ever actually comes up in statistics / Bayesian inference / etc.

I'm happy with reading suggestions if you find this question is too poorly conceived to give a good answer.

Comment: It sounds like you are seeking a multidimensional generalization of [Boltzmann's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Distributions_with_measured_constants).

Comment: Yes, that definitely looks interesting. To put my question in a somewhat more general frame, I'm interested in whether or not distributions with higher order moments like this may be "useful" in statistics or data analysis. For example, is there a distribution, similar in importance to the Gaussian, but parameterized by the first three moments, rather than the first two.

Comment: There are infinitely many distributional families parameterized by any finite collections of moments you care to name.

Comment: Indeed. For example, If all I know are the mean and covariance of a random variable, then there are infinitely many distributions it might have. However, among all such distributions the Gaussian [best represents my state of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy). The question then is, what distribution should I assume if I also knew all of the third order moments. It seems as though I can find such a distribution via Boltzmann's theorem, but I'm interested in whether this approach ever actually comes up in statistics / Bayesian inference / etc.

Comment: There's no maximum entropy distribution on the real line given the first three moments (there can be one on the half-line)

Answer (score 1):

The problem of determination of probability density from moments given up to an order N is treated in my PhD thesis (Construction of Random signals from their Higher Order Moments,1997, Imperial  College UK), where the Maximum Entropy is one method, which gives the solution as Exp(polynomial) and there are linear relations between the order N and higher order moments, the latter being functions of the first N ones. The thesis is published by AuthorHouse 2013